# find a limit of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Please ,how to prove that the limit of $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ is $0$ 
where $f(x,y)$ is  $\frac{x^2}{ \sqrt{x^3 + y^3}}$    .. which is not continuous there to prove that it is continuous there .. 
I know that the limit is $0$ (byy using lines )but don't know how to prove it

Comment: Try the limit along the line $y=mx$. What happens?

Comment: I tried many lines ans every times it ended at 0 .. but I need to prove it then

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If y= mx, as jdods suggested, the fraction is $\frac{x}{(x^3+ m^3x^3)^{1/2}}= \frac{x}{x^{3/2}(1+ m^3)^{1/2}}= x^{-1/2}(1+ m^3)^{1/3}$.  The limit is taken as x goes to 0.  I don't see how you could possibly have gotten 0!

Comment: please have a look at the edition

Comment: @jdods  pleas  ....

Comment: Another way be, let $x=r\cos{\theta$} and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ if $$lim_{x \to 0, y \to 0}$$ then $$lim_{r \to 0}$$ therefore the limit comes out to be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist: If $x=0$ gets fixed and $y\to 0$, we get $0$. But by following the arc $(x,y)=(t,\sqrt[3]{t^4-t^3})$ (which tends to $(0,0)$ as $t\downarrow 0$), we get that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}f(x,y)=\lim_{t\downarrow0}\frac{1}{t^2}$ which diverges.

Comment: Hello, how do you get $1/t^2$?

Comment: he means (x^4 - x^3 )^1/3

Comment: Thanks, fixed !

Comment: I think that is $(x,y)=(t,\sqrt[3]{t^8-t^3})$

Answer (score 0):

The function is not defined at $y=-x$ thus the limit does not exist. The function grows without bound in every small neighborhood of $(0,0)$

Comment: I think the argument of the square root is $x^3+y^3$, not $x^2+y^2$.